# I'm using downloadonly for another box. How can I configure repos for a different OS?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I have a standalone RHEL7 box and a networked Debian box with yum installed. I'm trying to use downloadonly in yum to download RPMs for the RHEL7 box.

I used:

- `sudo apt-get install yum`
- `yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly` (which failed as there were no repositories)
- `sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck https://...` (which fails as the system requires RHEL7 and I'm on a Debian box)

Comment: Use [yumdownloader](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yumdownloader)

Comment: How do I get yumdownloader? `sudo apt-get install yumdownloader` gives me "Unable to locate package yumdownloader" on Debian.

Comment: `apt install yum-utils`